# OpenCL in Eclipse-CDT (Windows) using AMD Graphics Card

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, opencl

I am trying to link OpenCL libraries with Eclipse (luna) CDT (with GCC, version-4.9.1) on my Windows(8.1,64 Bit) machine. I have installed AMD APP SDK 2.9-1.

To configure Eclipse, I followed this [tutorial](http://guipan8.freehostia.com/en/opencl/using-eclipse-for-opencl-programming) and linked the corresponding include folder (C:\Program Files(x86)\AMD APP SDK\2.9-1\include) and library (C:\Program Files(x86)\AMD APP SDK\2.9-1\lib\x86_64) on my machine.

To test the OpenCL libraries, I took the sample code from [here](http://www.fixstars.com/en/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/first-opencl-program/). But, when I am building the project, I am getting the following error.

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   make: *** [OpenCL_Test] Error 1 OpenCL_Test C/C++ Problem

How to fix this error?

Comment: can you post the solution for the rest of us please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this [link](http://guipan8.freehostia.com/en/opencl/using-eclipse-for-opencl-programming) for library and include folder setup. Additional step is to go to **Properties** -> **C/C++ build** -> **Setting** -> **Cross GCC Linker** -> **Binary Parser** (it's a tab). Under Binary Parsers, I ticked all of the options and it worked.